# Maven failing when specify dependency version as RELEASE or LATEST

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have 3 maven projects 'core', 'client-lib' and 'client'

- 'client-lib' includes 'core' as dependency with version as 'RELEASE'
- 'client' includes 'client-lib' as dependency with version as 'RELEASE'

However `mvn install` fails on 'client' with following error

Failed to collect dependencies at myorg:client-lib:jar:RELEASE: Failed to read artifact descriptor for myorg:client-lib:jar:RELEASE: Failed to resolve version for myorg:client-lib:jar:RELEASE -> [Help 1]

I have successfully used version 'RELEASE' to get latest version of dependencies on multiple projects. However, for this particular case it seems to not like it. If I however use specific version, build goes fine.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Have you tried emptying (delete) your Maven cache directory and/or the local repository? Before that you can try -U and -X to force updated dependency check and to get debug information. Oh, it looks like you don't use a groupId, try setting one.

Comment: A version `RELEASE` does simply not exist...if you really like to get the latest you should use a version range which is not really recommended but you can use it if you like...Best is to use particular versions so your build is reproducible.

Comment: @khmarbaise - I completely agree with you, however I am stuck with choice (and hence expectations set) before my time

Comment: @t0r0X - thank you for your suggestion of blowing local repo and rebuilding project did the trick

Comment: @Pushkar cool, glad your issue is solved :-) I'm adding a official answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try emptying (delete) your Maven cache directory and/or the local repository, then rebuild.

Besides that you can try -U and -X to force updated dependency check and to get more information about what Maven tries to do and dependency resolution.